# Convert list of elements into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I’m trying to use a gallery plugin that loads images from an array (script). I want to generate this array from a list of elements inside a container, such as:

```
<div id="gallery2">
  <img src="image01.jpg" title="Title Image 1"> 
  <img src="image02.jpg" title="Title Image 2"> 
  <img src="image03.jpg" title="Title Image 3"> 
  <img src="image04.jpg" title="Title Image 4"> 
  <img src="image05.jpg" title="Title Image 5"> 
  <img src="image06.jpg" title="Title Image 6"> 
</div>
```

to this:

```
arr = [
  {src: 'image01.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 1'},
  {src: 'image02.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 2'},
  {src: 'image03.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 3'},
  {src: 'image04.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 4'},
  {src: 'image05.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 5'},
  {src: 'image06.jpg', caption: 'Title Image 6'}
]
```

I’ve been trying some examples that I found over here, but with no luck. I think my resulting array is not a proper "javascript array", so it does not work. I’m using this code:

```
var arr = [];
$('#gallery2 img').each(function (index, element) {
  arr[arr.length] = "{ src:'" + $(this).attr('src') + "'";
  arr[arr.length] = "caption: '" + $(this).attr('title') + "'}";
});
arr = (arr.join(','));
```

Which results in:

```
{ src:'image01.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 1'},
{ src:'image02.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 2'}, 
{ src:'image03.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 3'}, 
{ src:'image04.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 4'}, 
{ src:'image05.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 5'}, 
{ src:'image06.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 6'}
```

so far it seams the array have the format i need, but, for some reason the function that loads this array of images is not working properly. The result is this:

```
<img src="{ src:'image01.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 1'},{ src:'image02.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 2'},{ src:'image03.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 3'}" alt="" title="">  ...and so on.
```

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is with the function that binds the data to the image tags...where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to return array.

```js
var data = $('#gallery2 img').map(function() {
  return {src: $(this).attr('src'), caption: $(this).attr('title')}
}).get();

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery2">
  <img src="image01.jpg" title="Title Image 1">
  <img src="image02.jpg" title="Title Image 2">
  <img src="image03.jpg" title="Title Image 3">
  <img src="image04.jpg" title="Title Image 4">
  <img src="image05.jpg" title="Title Image 5">
  <img src="image06.jpg" title="Title Image 6">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var arr = [];
$('#gallery2 img').each(function (index, element) {
  var tempObject = {};
  tempObject.src = $(this).attr('src');
  tempObject.caption = $(this).attr('title');
  arr.push(tempObject);
});
```

Comment: minor change needed: instead of `tempObject.title` it should be `tempObject.caption`

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify(arr)

Comment: thanks, but the result now is: [object Object],[object Object] ...and so on, there is anything else i can do?

Comment: @CarlosHidalgo Please post the part of your code where you use the array.. But basically it sounds like you need JSON.stringify(arr)

Comment: Im using the [images-grid.js](https://github.com/taras-d/images-grid) plugin, wich load a list of images like this:

$('#gallery').imagesGrid({
images: [ 
{ src:'image01.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 1'},{ src:'image02.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 2'}, { src:'image03.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 3'}, 
{ src:'image04.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 4'}, { src:'image05.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 5'}, { src:'image06.jpg',caption: 'Title Image 6'} 
]
});

This way it works, but I want to make it more easy for some users to add this to any content.

Comment: Many thanks, with the help of you, and all you guys I finally get what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$('#gallery2 img').each(function (index, element) {
    var el = {};
    el.src = $(this).attr('src');
    el.title = $(this).attr('title');
    arr.push(el);
});
```

Your implementation is trying to replicate the representation of the javascript object you want, so it result in a string. This way you build a real array of javascript objects.